# como puedo solucionar este error?

Tags: php, apache, docker

Estoy levantando un contenedor de docker en php con apache 7.4 con este comando.
`docker run -p 5000:80 -d -v $(pwd)/src:/var/wwww/html/ poophp`

y me arroja este error diciendo que el nombre de la imagen esta en mayusculas, cosa que no es asi

`docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`

ya he borrado todas mis imagenes y las he vuelto a descargar.

[este es el archivo dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YY2N.png)

estaba probando tambien hacerlo sinespecificar la ruta en el comando, no aparece el error pero no me da permisos.
[me da este error al ejecutar localhost:5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwmGl.png)

se que asi no va a funcionar apache porque debo especificar la ruta, pero lo probe y asi no me da el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Sé que esto tal vez no solucione tu problema, pero (copio textual):

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
```

Significa que el nombre del repositorio debe ser en minúsculas **únicamente**.